# Can strict transport security be enforced generally?

Tags: ubuntu, security, nginx, https, hsts

I would like to prevent users accessing my website using http.
Instead, I want to enforce the use of https.

Usually, I have my websites hosted at providers who simply have a checkbox "Enforce https".

In this case, I have my own Ubuntu (nginx) server.

I would like to know if I can also enforce https server wide, or do I have to work with a preload flag in the HSTS header?

Can anybody point me to a document that describes how to resolve this issue with my configuration?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Usually you need two `server` blocks where the one that listen on plain HTTP port redirect all requests to HTTPS:

```
server {
    listen               80;
    server_name          example.com;
    return               301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen               443 ssl;
    server_name          example.com;
    ssl_certificate      /path/to/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/privatekey;
    add_header           Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    # all the other configuration
}
```

If you also need to redirect all non-www domain name requests to www one (or vise versa), check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/896543/nginx-certbot-certificate-www-and-non-www) answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @IvanShatsky shows how to implement HSTS in Nginx (and I believe that's what you need).

Just to add some context to the answer:

- You want to have both HTTP → HTTPS redirect and HSTS header.
- To prevent all vulnerable scenarios you want HSTS header to include `preload` attribute (unless your TLD is HSTS-enabled, like `.dev` or `.app`).
- In order to add a domain to the preload list, you still need to submit it at https://hstspreload.org.

Since enabling `preload` is pretty much a one-way ticket, **safe rollout plan** make look like this:

The idea is to start small and gradually increment the expiration time and inclusion criteria.

- Find out all subdomains you have (consult DNS CNAME entries). Those may be served by your servers or 3rd party services
- Make sure the root domain and all subdomains can serve traffic over SSL/TLS (accessible via HTTPS)
- Ensure HTTP → HTTPS redirect is configured
- Set small expiration time, e.g. max-age=600 (10 minutes), make sure all systems operational
- Add includeSubDomains directive
- Make incremental changes to max-age. Aim for the value of 2 years
- Add preload directive and submit the domain to the HSTS preload list

[Ultimate guide to HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://www.maxivanov.io/http-strict-transport-security/).